# Do checkpoints make initial blockchain sync faster?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, nodes, blockchain-import

Do the checkpoint hashes in checkpoints.cpp make the syncing go faster? Why or why not?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The daemon doesn't [check transaction signatures](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/0fde289e2f29fa56759d842b2517885637595497/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L2691) when under a checkpoint.

There are other possible optimizations, but I think that's the only one active right now.